# Simple C# check?

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, contacts, isset

I am new to c# and making simple contact form, for now i got this in view

```
      @{


    var customerName = Request["customerName"];
    var customerEmail = Request["customerEmail"]; 
    var customerRequest = Request["customerRequest"];
    var errorMessage = "";
    var debuggingFlag = false;
    try {
        // Initialize WebMail helper
        WebMail.SmtpServer = "your-SMTP-host";
        WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
        WebMail.UserName = "your-user-name-here";
        WebMail.Password = "your-account-password";
        WebMail.From = "your-email-address-here";

        // Send email
        WebMail.Send(to: customerEmail,
            subject: "Help request from - " + customerName,
            body: customerRequest
        );
    }
    catch (Exception ex ) {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

It is ok for now, but how to check in POST varibales exist i know in PHP

```
if (isset($_POST["customerName"]) && !empty($_POST["customerName"])) {
}
```

very easy, but how to do that in C#

Comment: Just typing $_post equivalent c# in Google provided like dozens of results. Do at least some research before posting...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check it against `null` like:

```
if(Request["customerName"] != null)
{
 //Post key exists
}
```

Comment: Consider also using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.